# How to understand python slicing with a negative k index?

Tags: python

Can someone explain why `a[:5:-1] != a[:5][::-1]`?

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> a[:5][::-1]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> a[:5:-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6]
```

Comment: looks like :: operates descending. Just kind of guessing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general syntax of slicings is

```
a[start:stop:step]
```

You can omit any of the three values `start`, `stop`, or `step`.  If you omit `step`, it always defaults to `1`.  The default values of `start` and `stop`, by contrast, depend on the sign of `step`: if `step` is positive, `start` defaults to `0` and `stop` to `len(a)`.  If `step` is negative, `start` defaults to `len(a) - 1` and `stop` to "beginning of the list".

So `a[:5:-1]` is the same as `a[9:5:-1]` here,

while `a[:5][::-1]` is the same as `a[0:5][4::-1]`.

(Note that it's impossible to give the default value for `stop` explicitly if `step` is negative.  The stop value is non-inclusive, so `0` would be different from "beginning of the list".  Using `None` would be equivalent to giving no value at all.)

Answer (score 1):

What `a[:5][::-1]` says is that program should firstly take elements until 5th element of the dataset and then reverse them (take every one element starting with the last one).

Contrary to that, `a[:5:-1]` says that you should take elements until 5th element starting with the last element (take every one element starting with the last one).

Answer (score 0):

a[:5] returns an array, indexes 0 through 4, that you're then negatively indexing as a second operation. a[:5:-1] indexes the original array negatively.